# Can someone suggest why the second player is not being authorised?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
UsernameFile = open("C:/Ishaan's Folder/Homework (Year 11)/Computing/NEA Programming Project/Usernames.txt", "r")
PasswordFile = open("C:/Ishaan's Folder/Homework (Year 11)/Computing/NEA Programming Project/Passwords.txt", "r")
ScoresFileIshaanFolder = open("C:/Ishaan's Folder/Homework (Year 11)/Computing/NEA Programming Project/Scores.txt", "a")
PlayerOneAuthorised = False
PlayerTwoAuthorised = False

#Read lines until we reach the place in the file that we want.
UsernameLine = UsernameFile.readline()
PasswordLine = PasswordFile.readline()

#To check whether the Player One is authorised
print("Player One Authentication.")
Username1 = str(input("Please enter your username: "))
print(Username1)

while UsernameLine != "":
    UsernameLine = UsernameFile.readline()
    if Username1 in str(UsernameLine):
        Password1 = input("""Username authorised
Please enter your password: """)
        while PasswordLine != "":
            PasswordLine = PasswordFile.readline()
            if Password1 in str(PasswordLine):
                print("Password Authorised")
                print(Username1, " is now authorised to play this game.")
                PlayerOneAuthorised = True
            else:
                NewPassword1 = input("""Password not authorised
Please re-enter your password: """)
            break
    else:
        newUsername1= input("""Username not authorised.
Please re-enter your username: """)
        Username1 = newUsername1
        if newUsername1 in str(UsernameLine):
            Password1 = input("""Username authorised
Please enter your password: """)
            while PasswordLine != "":
                PasswordLine = PasswordFile.readline()
                if Password1 in str(PasswordLine):
                    print("Password Authorised")
                    print(Username1, "is now authorised to play this game.")
                    PlayerOneAuthorised = True
                else:
                    NewPassword1 = input("""Password not authorised
Please re-enter your password: """)
                    if NewPassword1 in str(PasswordLine):
                        print("Password Authorised")
                        print(Username1, "is now authorised to play this game.")
                        PlayerOneAuthorised = True
                break
        else:
            print("""Username not authorised.
You are not allowed to play this game.""")
            input("Press enter to exit")
            exit()
    break

#To check whether Player Two is authorised
print("Player Two Authentication")
Username2 = str(input("Please enter your username: "))

while UsernameLine != "":
    UsernameLine = UsernameFile.readline()
    if Username2 in str(UsernameLine):
        Password2 = input("""Username authorised
Please enter your password: """)
        while PasswordLine != "":
            PasswordLine = PasswordFile.readline()
            if Password2 in str(PasswordLine):
                print("Password Authorised")
                print(Username2, "is now authorised to play this game.")
                PlayerTwoAuthorised = True
            else:
                NewPassword2 = input("""Password not authorised
Please re-enter your password: """)
            break
    else:
        newUsername2= input("""Username not authorised.
Please re-enter your username: """)
        Username2 = newUsername2

        if newUsername2 in str(UsernameLine):
            Password2 = input("""Username authorised
Please enter your password: """)
            while PasswordLine != "":
                PasswordLine = PasswordFile.readline()
                if Password2 in str(PasswordLine):
                    print("Password Authorised")
                    print(Username2, "is now authorised to play this game.")
                    PlayerTwoAuthorised = True
                else:
                    NewPassword2 = input("""Password not authorised
Please re-enter your password: """)
                    if NewPassword2 in str(PasswordLine):
                        print("Password Authorised")
                        print(Username2, "is now authorised to play this game.")
                        PlayerTwoAuthorised = True
                break
        else:
            print("""Username not authorised.
You are not allowed to play this game.""")
            input("Press enter to exit")
            exit()
    break
```

This is the username file:

```
Ishaan
Brandon
Harvey
```

This is the password file:

```
Ishaan
Brandon
Harvey
```

When I enter "Ishaan" as the username and password, it is being authorised but when I enter either "Brandon" or "Harvey" it says that those usernames are not in the file.

I believe this is a problem with reading the file.
I have tried doing everything I can. My friends told me to add a function instead of creating it individually, but I am not that confident with functions. So if you think you know the answer please comment.

Comment: Please start your code in your debugger and step line by line through your code until you can localize the problem. Create a [mcve] and post it. Don't dump your whole project and expect others to debug it. You also should remove user input and replace it with values.

Comment: `UsernameFile` is not defined in your code.

Comment: You don't even check all usernames in the file. You read the first username and compare it with the input. There is no connection between username and password. All users can use all password. I think it's easier to start over than to fix this project. You should start with pen and paper. Draw the program flow.

Comment: @ThomasSablik All Ineed is the function that reads all the usernames in the file. I have also added the UsernameFile in my code which I had forgotten above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is far too much code for this task. You need to better structure your coding - seperate it in task. You never read all the usernames and passwords.

What you need is to build a data strucure that holds user and the password, for that you need to read in both files, line by line and "connect" the lines.

If you need to check for login you just use that structure you build and look it up. The "Need to login code" parts do not need to handle file reading at all.

**Create password and user file:**

```
with open ("user.txt","w") as u, open("pass.txt","w") as p:
    for num in range(3):
        u.write(f"user{num+1}\n")
        p.write(f"pass{num+1}\n")
```

**Read file in and store in dictionary:**

```
# read all users/pw into a dictionary
users = {}
# open both files
with open("user.txt") as u, open("pass.txt") as p:
    # connect the lines using zip() with pairs the lines into tuples
    for (user,pw) in zip(u,p):
        # set the user/pw in your dictionary
        users[user.strip()] = pw.strip()

# don't print in your application     
print(users)
```

**Output:**

```
{'user1': 'pass1', 'user2': 'pass2', 'user3': 'pass3'}
```

---

**Program using the dict:**

With that out of hand you can easily check if a user can log in:

```
while True:
    user = input("Enter user name (empty user to quit): ")
    if not user:  
        break
    # never explain that this user is not present, ask for pw and
    # quite with a vague message that either user or pw wrong for
    # "more" security
    pw = input("Enter passphrase: ")

    # look if that key is in the dict and if so if the passphrase matches
    if users.get(user) == pw:
        print("Logged in.")
        break
    else:
        print("Invalid user.")
if not user:
    print("Quitting")
    exit(1)
else:
    print("Gooooooo")
    # logged in
```

Comment: I am getting an error that says: "TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.TextIOWrapper"

I was trying to read the file into a dictionary when this happened

Comment: @Ishaan my code does not give this error. Yours might, if you tried to change it from mine. Debug it and if its not workig ask a new question, post the problematic part of your code as[mre].

Comment: How do I change your code to fit mine? I already have a username and password file created with the names in it

Comment: @Ishaan you replace `'user.txt'` when reading by `"C:/Ishaan's Folder/Homework (Year 11)/Computing/NEA Programming Project/Usernames.txt"` and similarly for your password file? in the line `# open both file` - `with open("user.txt") as u, open("pass.txt") as p:` ?

Comment: I have just put your code in and it worked thanks a ton!